# How to give alias to a function calling from select query where columns are joint by ||','||

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT 
  ACCOUNT_NUMBER||','||
  pkg_name.function_name(ACCOUNT_NUMBER, null) as "FLAG"
  FROM table_name
  where clause='value';
```

The expectation here is to display the columns below

| ACCOUNT_NUMBER','FLAG |
| --- |
| 12345,Y |
| 2323,N |

Can someone pls help me to find out the correct query?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, result you got is OK (meaning: `12345,Y` is OK). But, the whole column's heading is set to `FLAG` - you'd want to get `ACCOUNT_NUMBER','FLAG`.

In that case, enclose such a string into double quotes, e.g.

```
SQL> select dummy "ACCOUNT_NUMBER','FLAG" from dual;

ACCOUNT_NUMBER','FLAG                --> here it is
------------------------------
X

SQL>
```

---

If you want to give alias to function's result and then concatenate that alias to account number, then you could use a CTE (or even a correlated subquery):

```
WITH
   temp
   AS
      (SELECT account_number AS anum,
              pkg_name.function_name (account_number, NULL) AS flag
         FROM table_name
        WHERE clause = 'value')
SELECT anum || ',' || flag as result
  FROM temp
```

---

Here are a few examples:

Function:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_flag (par_deptno IN NUMBER)
  2     RETURN VARCHAR2
  3  IS
  4  BEGIN
  5     RETURN CASE WHEN par_deptno <= 20 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END;
  6  END;
  7  /

Function created.
```

An ordinary concatenation:

```
SQL> SELECT deptno || ',' || f_flag (deptno) AS result
  2    FROM emp
  3   WHERE ROWNUM <= 5;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
20,Y
30,N
30,N
20,Y
30,N
```

Using a CTE:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     temp
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT deptno, f_flag (deptno) AS flag
  5           FROM emp
  6          WHERE ROWNUM <= 5)
  7  SELECT deptno || ',' || flag AS result
  8    FROM temp;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
20,Y
30,N
30,N
20,Y
30,N
```

Using correlated subquery within a CTE:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     temp
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT e.deptno, (SELECT f_flag (e.deptno) FROM DUAL) AS flag
  5           FROM emp e
  6          WHERE ROWNUM <= 5)
  7  SELECT deptno || ',' || flag AS result
  8    FROM temp;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
20,Y
30,N
30,N
20,Y
30,N

SQL>
```

I still think that the simplest concatenation is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the response Littlefoot , but I am trying to call a function inside that select and want to give it an alias then want to concatenate it with other columns like 'ACCOUNT_NUMBER'

Comment: Aha; see if a CTE helps in that case (in edited answer). In my opinion, there's no much benefit in doing that. Why would you want to do it, anyway?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Littlefoot , your solution worked 
Actually I need to modify one report(in csv format) where we need to add one column that should come from function